# Why does my Debian show a blank sreen after boot before login?

Tags: debian

My Debian's version is 10.3,with no GUI,and runs on an old computer(RAM:400MB,CPU:celeron).I boot it and found that after showing some boot logs,the screen showed a blank;However,I boot the system on recovery mode,things ran well.It's so strange.

Comment: Did you try hitting Enter on the blank screen?

Comment: Yes,I did.But then a sound from the harddisk(maybe another part)occured,and the screen still remained blank.Actually,I can use my syestem normally,but only in root user.(on recovery mode).

Comment: »» the screen showed a blank screen «« : *Can* happen. One of my (many) computers boots to blank screen with Debian. A harmless hardware failure ?

Comment: What's more,not only after boot,it happened while using X11.I only ran xterm and installed something,after some time,unfortunately,the screen shows a blank.Maybe its'a "harmless hardware failure"(after all my computer is too old).